# async await in node callback

Tags: node.js, async-await

I have a service, which uses a 3rd party package.

```
exports.FOO = (options, cb) => {
  const outputPath = 'bar'
  const storePDF = async (data) => {}
  const sendBack = (outputPath, cb) => {
    fs.readFile(outputPath, encoding, async (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
       return cb(err)
      }
      if (options.source) {
       await store(data)
      }
      cb(null, data);
    })
  }
  ThirdParty.run(err => {
     if (err) {
       return cb(err)
     };
     // read the file and send it back
     sendBack(outputPath, cb)
  })
}
```

I want to upgrade this package, but it has some breaking changes, the new usage looks like this:

```
await ThirdParty.setup()
await ThirdParty.run()
```

I really want to keep the callback, since this service is used like this across the whole application. I have tried to make FOO `async` and call `sendBack` after `await ThirdParty.run()`, but I am getting.

> node_modules/async/dist/async.js:966
>
> if (fn === null) throw new Error("Callback was already called.");
>
> Error: Callback was already called.

```
exports.FOO = async (options, cb) => {
  const outputPath = 'bar'
  const storePDF = async (data) => {}
  const sendBack = (outputPath, cb) => {
    fs.readFile(outputPath, encoding, async (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
       return cb(err)
      }
      if (options.source) {
       await store(data)
      }
      cb(null, data);
    })
  }
  await ThirdParty.setup()
  await ThirdParty.run()
  sendBack(outputPath, cb)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the call to an await. then call your callback like you've done before. If the call failed, handle it in the `catch` block.

```
exports.FOO = async (options, cb) => {
  //...
  try {
    await ThirdParty.run();
    // read the file and send it back
    sendBack(outputPath, cb)
  } catch (err)
     return cb(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but -as I wrote- this exactly what I have tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
    exports.FOO = async (options, cb) => {
  const outputPath = 'bar'
  const storePDF = async (data) => {}
  const sendBack = (outputPath, cb) => {
    fs.readFile(outputPath, encoding, async (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
       return cb(err)
      }
      if (options.source) {
       await store(data)
      }
      cb(null, data);
    })
  }
  await ThirdParty.setup()
  await ThirdParty.run()
  sendBack(outputPath, cb) //Why are you calling sendBack here shouldn't be return without calling the function like recursion?
}
```

Comment: If you take a look at the original code, you can see, that ThirdParty generates the file, and when it is done, sendBack reads it, and sends it back in the callback.

Comment: If you want to return read data you can simply return data instead of sendBack(..)